# marker detection and 3d model display for corresponding markers in ios(using ARkit)

Tags: ios, arkit

Previously i have used vuforia(unity) to developed an AR app for iOS. Now i have to implement the same app using ARKit.

`ARKit` is awesome except there is no marker detection.

I have tried to use vision to detect markers and not successful so far.
can i have some samples for marker detection and displaying 3d models on the markers for iOS ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to achieve what your are looking for, although arguably the most simple is using images are markers.

As of `ARKit` 1.5 you are able to use `ReferenceImages` to place AR Content which are essentially the same as the markers you would use in `Vuforia` or `EasyAR`.

For your information a `referenceImage` is simply:

> An image to be recognized in the real-world environment during a
>   world-tracking AR session.

To make use of this function you need to pass in a :

> collection of reference images to your session configuration's
>   detectionImages property.

Which can be set like so:

```
var detectionImages: Set<ARReferenceImage>! { get set }
```

An important thing to note with `ARKit 1.5` is that unlike `Vuforia`  which can allow `extended tracking` of images:

> Image detection doesn't continuously track real-world movement of the
>   image or track when the image disappears from view. Image detection
>   works best for cases where AR content responds to static images in the
>   scene—for example, identifying art in a museum or adding animated
>   elements to a movie poster.

As @Alexander said, your best bet for learning how this may be appropriate to your situation is looking at the `SampleCode` and `Documentation` online, which is available here:

[Recognizing Images In An AR Experience](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience)

The core points however are these:

**To Enable Image Detection:**

You need to first provide one or more `ARReferenceImage` resources. These can be added manually using the `AR` asset catalog in `Xcode`, remembering that your must enter the physical size of the image in Xcode as accurately as possible since `ARKit` relies on this information to determine the distance of the image from the camera.

`ARReferenceImages` can also be created on the fly using the following methods:

```
init(CGImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation, physicalWidth: CGFloat)
```

> Which creates a new reference image from a Core Graphics image
>   object.

```
init(CVPixelBuffer, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation, physicalWidth: CGFloat)
```

> Which creates a new reference image from a Core Video pixel buffer.

Having done this, you then need to create a world tracking configuration in which you pass in your ARReferenceImages before running your ARSession e.g:

```
guard let referenceImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else { return }

let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.detectionImages = referenceImages
session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

**Handling Detection Of Images:**

When an `ARReferenceImage` is detected by your `ARSession` and `ARImageAnchor` is created which simply provides:

> Information about the position and orientation of an image detected in
>   a world-tracking AR session.

If image detection is successful therefore, you will need to use the following `ARSCNViewDelegate` callback to handle placement of your objects etc:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) { }
```

An example of using this to handle placement of your 3D content would be like so:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        //1. If Out Target Image Has Been Detected Than Get The Corresponding Anchor
        guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

        //2. Get The Targets Name
        let name = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.name!

        //3. Get The Targets Width & Height
        let width = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width
        let height = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height

        //4. Log The Reference Images Information
        print("""
            Image Name = \(name)
            Image Width = \(width)
            Image Height = \(height)
            """)

        //5. Create A Plane Geometry To Cover The ARImageAnchor
        let planeNode = SCNNode()
        let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
        planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
        planeNode.opacity = 0.25
        planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry

        //6. Rotate The PlaneNode To Horizontal
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

        //7. The Node Is Centered In The Anchor (0,0,0)
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        //8. Create AN SCNBox
        let boxNode = SCNNode()
        let boxGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)

        //9. Create A Different Colour For Each Face
        let faceColours = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.blue, UIColor.cyan, UIColor.yellow, UIColor.gray]
        var faceMaterials = [SCNMaterial]()

        //10. Apply It To Each Face
        for face in 0 ..< 5{
            let material = SCNMaterial()
            material.diffuse.contents = faceColours[face]
            faceMaterials.append(material)
        }
        boxGeometry.materials = faceMaterials
        boxNode.geometry = boxGeometry

        //11. Set The Boxes Position To Be Placed On The Plane (node.x + box.height)
        boxNode.position = SCNVector3(0 , 0.05, 0)

        //12. Add The Box To The Node
        node.addChildNode(boxNode)
    }
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot! Thanks! I was just wondering if there is a way to do it without "images". I'd prefer to use a much simpler marker. Something like a QR-Code but that does not seem to be possible? Can you think of other solutions if the marker should be something more basic?